# Doubt regarding statistical testing of predictions made by two different time series models.

Tags: time-series

What test (parametric or non parametric)  do you suggest to test the significant difference between the predictions made by two different models used in forecasting a given time series?

Comment: I am not (yet) a time series guy, so you get a comment from me.  If they were any other model the following would be valid.  I could look at their prediction quality: in aggregate (R^2, AIC/c,...), in leave one out, in leave several out (aka with cross validation).  I could look at their "physics" - how well they relate to the "physics" being modeled.  If there are multi-dimensional inputs then I can look at "leave one out" in the inputs.  I could use AIC-weight based model-mixing to determine if/how they can be additively combined - thus saying "both" instead of selecting just one.